# How to create a line like crayon with Beamer

Tags: diagrams

I want to create a custom `beamer` line , for my template to look something like crayon like picture below:

[image: . How can I create it ?]

Comment: It is not about `beamer` but diagramming.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document. Also it would be great if you could elaborate a bit more on what you mean with "beamer line".

Comment: If I understand correctly, the OP asks for a specific *style of line*, not a particular diagram.

Answer (score 12):

This should get you going:

```
\documentclass[border=0.125cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[crayon/.style={very thick, line cap=round, line join=round,
  decoration={random steps, segment length=0.5pt, amplitude=0.25pt}, decorate}]

\foreach \l/\c [count=\y] in {A/blue!50!gray, B/orange, C/green!50!brown, D/brown!50!black}
   \path [crayon, draw=\c] (0,-\y/2) -- (6,-\y/2) node [at start, left, font=\sffamily, text=\c] {\l};

\path [crayon, draw=red!75!black] (0,0) -- (3,-3) -- (6,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With PSTricks just for fun!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}
\pstVerb{realtime srand}
\psset{linejoin=1}

\def\curlyline[#1](#2,#3)(#4,#5)#6{%
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=#6]{#2}{#4}{t #5 #3 sub #4 #2 sub div t #2 sub mul #3 add .25 Rand sub 30 div add}{P}
    \psnline[#1](0,\Pnodecount){P}}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-2.2,-2.2)(2,0)
\foreach \y/\l/\c in {0/A/red,-1/B/green,-2/C/blue}{\rput(-2.2,\y){\textcolor{\c}{\l}}\curlyline[linecolor=\c](-2,\y)(2,\y){150}}
\curlyline[linecolor=orange](-2,0)(0,-2.2){150}
\curlyline[linecolor=orange](0,-2.2)(2,0){150}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]